# ¿Puede "teja" denominar un objeto que sería llevado por las olas del mar?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, méxico

George Louderback analizó un resumen de una carta. En enero de 1840 el juez de paz de Branciforte, México, dijo:

> ... que en los dias 16 y 17 hizo gran estrago el mar. Salió de su seno más de 200 varas y se llevó toda **la teja** destinada para la nación.

Este mismo juez fue encargado con entregar, y luego acusado de robar, **tejas de barro**. El reporte que él mismo da, podría ser una mentira o hasta un error. Pero no sé si unas olas podrían arrastrar unas tejas de barro; tal vez si las tejas fuesen delgadas y estuvieran guardadas a la orilla del agua... Pero la verdad es que jamás lo he visto y no sé qué tan posible es.

Pero ¿y si *la teja* no fueran tejas de barro? Louderback recuenta que el profesor Rudolph Schevill le representó que la forma singular podría abarcar otras materias, tales como la madera. En construcciones de adobe, más allá de las tejas de barro, se ocupaban por lo menos vigas de madera. Pero esa extensión de sentido la RAE no parece respaldarla; solamente hacia otras cosas con forma acanalada. No creo que ninguna casa de adobe usase pura madera en el techo porque tenían muy poca obra de madera. Cabe mencionar que había también casas de palizada en el pueblo.

¿Podremos decir con certitud si aquella *teja* era de barro?

[image: Carta del 1840]

Comment: Yo no veo problema en que una marejada o un tsunami se haya llevado toneladas de tejas, sean de barro o de cualquier otro material. La fuerza del mar puede ser impresionante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las olas provocadas por un temporal marino relativamente fuerte (ni siquiera hace falta que llegue a huracán) son [perfectamente capaces de inundar poblaciones costeras, romper muros y paredes, y destruir casas y otras construcciones en pleno siglo XXI](https://www.antena3.com/noticias/sociedad/video-estragos-temporal-canarias_201811185bf1d4af0cf2abe03a72a138.html). No veo por qué no iban a poder llevarse consigo unas simples tejas de barro, almacenadas a saber cómo, hace casi dos siglos.

El relato que aportas menciona que el mar *«salió de su seno más de 200 varas»*. La [vara](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bMH7x5e#ILZooqC) es una antigua unidad de medida, equivalente a unos 0.85 metros, por tanto estamos hablando de un temporal que hizo que el mar se adentrase en tierra más de 170 metros; o dicho en lenguaje periodístico: suficiente para inundar casi dos campos de fútbol.
Una masa de agua con fuerza suficiente para superar el desnivel y los obstáculos encontrados a su paso a lo largo de tal distancia, te puedo asegurar que arrastraría cientos de tejas de barro como si fueran hojas llevadas por el viento.

Dices además que este hombre, tras asegurar que el mar se llevó "toda la teja", fue acusado de robar "tejas de barro".
Creo que hay elementos suficientes como para concluir que **sí: "la teja" se refiere a "tejas de barro", y pueden ser arrastradas por el mar**.